# lookup value from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am implementing pivot table modules just like MS excel pivot table.
I am using pandas dataframe modules.

anyway..

I am wondering how to look up value from a dataframe by keys.

Elapsed time is critical.

Please complete my sample code below.

```
import pandas as pd

def getTestDataFrame():
    data=[]

    # generating 10000000 records
    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(1000):
            data.append( (i ,j, i+j) )


    dataFrame=pd.DataFrame( data, columns=["key_1", "key_2", "myvalue"] )

    # setting index to key columns
    dataFrame=dataFrame.set_index(['key_1','key_2'])

    # data sample
    print dataFrame.head()

    return dataFrame



if __name__ == "__main__":

    myDataframe=getTestDataFrame()

    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(1000):
            key1, key2= i, j
            '''
            how can i lookup "myvalue" column value 
              from "myDataframe" by key columns("key_1", "key_2")?
            '''
            # elapsed time is critical
            # please complete my code
```

Comment: Why not use pandas' buitin `pivot_table` method instead?

Comment: In case of large size data, the pivoting speed of pivot_table is so slow.
So I am implementing pivot table manualy with groupby, melt modules of pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct pandas lookup syntax in this case would be:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

    myDataframe=getTestDataFrame()

    for i in range(10000):
        for j in range(1000):
            key1, key2= i, j

            myvalueOut = myDataframe.loc[key1,key2]['myvalue']
```

Unfortunately, I can't really speak much to your speed issue; pandas takes whatever time it requires in order to do the lookup, I have no control over that.

However, if the pandas lookup is still running too slow for you, one alternative data structure that you might try, instead of pandas, would be a [nested dictionary](http://ohuiginn.net/mt/2010/07/nested_dictionaries_in_python.html), which you would implement such that `key1` would cover the first level of nesting, and `key2` would cover the second.  Although I don't know very much about how pandas works internally, I'm pretty sure I've read before that Python dictionaries are basically just [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), meaning that the lookup time for a Python dictionary should always be O(1), i.e., the fastest possible.

Comment: I tested your code. I'm going to make pivoting table with paging functionality. The Current page data cells are only needed. The speed of yours is fairly good for my module. Thank a lot.